# dynamic function/state calls fail to be inline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic

i have a bunch of states:

```
const [player1,setPlayer1] = useState()
const [player2,setPlayer2] = useState()
const [player3,setPlayer3] = useState()
const [player4,setPlayer4] = useState()
```

which I need to call the setplayer4 if the position that I select is 4 for example
so.

```
if (position===4){
setPlayer`${position}(something)
```

which doesnt work, what would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dynamically construct variable names in Javascript. You can do the following instead

1. Use array indices to determine which setter to use

```
const [player1,setPlayer1] = useState()
const [player2,setPlayer2] = useState()
const [player3,setPlayer3] = useState()
const [player4,setPlayer4] = useState()

const setPlayers = [setPlayer1, setPlayer2, setPlayer3, setPlayer4]


// In your handler
if (position === 4) {
  setPlayers[position - 1](something)
}
```

2. Use objects so that you use dynamic keys

```
const [player1,setPlayer1] = useState()
const [player2,setPlayer2] = useState()
const [player3,setPlayer3] = useState()
const [player4,setPlayer4] = useState()

const setPlayers = {
  player1: setPlayer1, 
  player2: setPlayer2, 
  player3: setPlayer3, 
  player4: setPlayer4
}


// In your handler
if (position === 4) {
  setPlayers[`player${position}`](something)
}
```

3. If state is related, tie it together in a single object

```
// Use arrays if you have non-deterministic number of players
const [players, setPlayers] = {
  player1: null,
  player2: null,
  player3: null,
  player4: null,
}

// In your handler
if (position === 4) {
  setPlayers({
    ...players,
    player4: something
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you I think this will work, the first scenario